# Ruby on Rails tutorial questions, need help in clarifying thoughts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In RoR Tutorials,

test/test_helper.rb

```
...

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

...
```

It is clearly shown that function "is_logged_in?" is defined inside the class ActiveSupport::TestCase, however, how is that possible that a integration test of class ActionDispatch is able to find it? As shown:

test/integration/user_signup_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

...

  test "valid signup information with account activation" do

...

    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token", email: user.email)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template "users/show"
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

end
```

Based on my understanding, unless "is_logged_in?" is defined in the class ActionDispatch, it should throw error like "nomethoderror, undefined is_logged_in?", however why is that not the case?

Answer (score 1):

`ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` inherits, amongst many others, from `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, so any modification done in `ActiveSupport::TestCase` will be available in the child class as well.

Understand that in `test_helper.rb`, `class ActiveSupport::TestCase` does not create a new class but instead reopens an existing class to add some changes.